# Flutter push notification FCM not navigating on launch

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

There is a flutter app. Push notifications are being sent using FCM.

The desired behavior is that on clicking the notification, it should take to a screen where notification details are being shown. That screen is implemented.

On clicking the notification when app is in background, the click is taking to the desired screen but when the app is launched on clicking, it is opening the home screen and not the desired notification screen.

Push Notifications Service code.

```
class PushNotificationsManager {

  PushNotificationsManager._();

  factory PushNotificationsManager() => _instance;

  static final PushNotificationsManager _instance = PushNotificationsManager._();

  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  bool _initialized = false;

  Future<void> init() async {
    if (!_initialized) {
      // For iOS request permission first.
      _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();
      //configure
      _firebaseMessaging.configure(
        //Triggered if a message is received whilst the app is in foreground
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print("onMessage: $message");
//          _navigateToItemDetail(message);
//          _showItemDialog(message);
        },
        //this line causes hot reload error
//        onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
        //Triggered if a message is received if the app was terminated
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print("onLaunch: $message");
          _navigateToItemDetail(message);
        },
        //Triggered if a message is received whilst the app is in background
        onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print("onResume: $message");
          _navigateToItemDetail(message);
        },
      );

      // For testing purposes print the Firebase Messaging token
      String token = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
      print("FirebaseMessaging token: $token");

      _initialized = true;
    }
  }


  void _navigateToItemDetail(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    print("Navigating to notification screen");
    bool isValid = message["data"]["title"] != null && message["data"]["body"] != null;

    if(!isValid) return;

    navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(notificationScreenRoute, (route) => false, arguments: message);
   // navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(notificationScreenRoute, arguments: message);
  }
}
```

main.dart -- Here I am initializing push notifications service

```
//global navigator key,used where buildContext is not available (in business logic)
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  //init Hive
  await initHiveDb();

  PushNotificationsManager _pushNotificationManager = PushNotificationsManager();
  _pushNotificationManager.init();

  // get the dynamic link service
  final DynamicLinkService _dynamicLinkService = DynamicLinkService();
  // call handle dynamic links
  await _dynamicLinkService.handleDynamicLinks();

  //run app, restrict orientaton to portrait up
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: kMaroonColor
  ));
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]).then((_) {
    runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
        theme: (appLightTheme).copyWith(
            //textTheme: GoogleFonts.latoTextTheme()
        ),
        onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        home: App()
      )
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you app is not running, your `MainActivity` that extends `FlutterFragmentActivity` is not running too. So since you FlutterActivity is not ready when launching the App, you cannot navigate between your Flutter pages until it gets loaded

Comment: Okay. So what is the turnaround for this. How do I make sure the navigation happens?

Comment: It depends. One way is to use system notification. Each notification you send to the user, you can save it's copy in a database with a field like `seen` that keeps the value `false` by default and change to `true` when navigation happens to the specific page. I mean something like facebook notification

Comment: I just want to show the screen once on clicking. I don't want to store the notifications.

Comment: This is possible only if the app is running. Otherwise, the default Home page is loaded. Does this answer your question ?